# detect python variable to convert in Cython

Tags: python, cython, cythonize

how to detect python variable to convert in Cython?
For example, what are the variables in the following program (Python), what's their equivalent on Cython?

## Python

```
import pickle
import struct
from pynput.mouse import Listener, Controller
mysocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn, addr = mysocket .accept()  
mouse = Controller() 
payload_size = struct.calcsize(">L")  
data = b""  
frame = pickle.loads(..., encoding="bytes") 
ftr = cv2.imdecode(frame, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

How to identify the type of data the variables below:

```
mysocket 
conn
addr
mouse
payload_size
data 
frame 
ftr
```

## Edit

```
cdef mysocket = socket
cdef conn = socket
cdef addr = ()
cdef mouse = Controller()
cdef int payload_size = struct.calcsize(">L")
cdef bytes data = b""
...
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you know about the `type()` function?

Comment: @alec_djinn type mysocket is <class 'socket.socket'> and type conn is <class 'socket.socket'> and type addr=<class 'tuple'>

Comment: Mostly you don't. They're just Python classes so don't benefit from typing. It's possible you can convert the images to something (memoryview maybe?)

Comment: My problem was solved, thank you all. I read a series of resources on the Internet and found out how to solve my problem. I am editing my own question